# pytest_addoption always taking the default value

Tags: python, pytest, command-line-arguments, typer

I am using `typer` library for the CLI. Now in my `cli.py` I have following command:

```
@app.command("run")
def run(
    markers: str = typer.Option(
        "login",
        "--markers",
        help=(
            "Marker to run different tests. You can also use 'and', 'or',"
            " 'not' to select of deselect certain tests."
        ),
    ),
    report: bool = False,
    app_file: str = typer.Option(
        "abc",
        "--app_file",
        show_default=False,
    ),
):
    """Runs the tests for the given markers"""
    commands = ["pytest", "-m", markers]
    if report:
        xml_report = "--junitxml=test-reports/xml/report.xml"
        html_report = "--html=test-reports/html/report.html"
        commands.append(f"{xml_report} {html_report}")
    logger.debug(f"Running command: {' '.join(commands)}")
    subprocess.run(commands)
```

and my conftest.py looks like this:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--app_file', action='store', default="def")

@pytest.fixture
def app_file_name(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--app_file")

@pytest.fixture
def ios_web_driver(app_file_name):
    iwd = DriverSetting(name=app_file_name)
    iwd.init_webdriver()
    print("driver len")
    yield iwd.drivers
```

And after building the project when I execute:
`my_command run -markers='login' --app_file='ghi'`
Then the `--app_file` value is always `def`(see conftest.py)

My pytest.ini looks like this:

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]

log_cli = True
log_cli_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
log_cli_format = %(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s
junit_suite_name = mobile-test-client
junit_family = xunit1
junit_logging = DEBUG
log_cli_level = INFO
```

Comment: Yeah sure since you defined it as `app_file` but are passing `app_name` on the CLI

Comment: @dosas that was a typo. But I still get the error.

Comment: `ERROR: ugage: pytest [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]`
`pytest: error: unrecognized arguments: --app_file=ghi`

Comment: It works for me using `pytest -s --app_file=ghi test.py`

Comment: when I add `-s --app_file=ghi` the error says it needs a file name or path, not text/string. So if in the command line i specify the `--app_file` it should take the value from the command line not from the default value in conftest.py